# Selenium IDE returns false when comparing a longer digit number with shorter (e.g. 11>9, returns false)

Tags: selenium

```
store | 11 | x
store | 9 | y
verifyEval | storedVars['x']>storedVars['y'] | true
```

returns false. If the numbers are of same length (e.g. 9>5) it works fine. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: An obvious (possible) reason would be that the values are stored as strings; '11' < '9' < 'a'.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, Any idea how to resolve this? How can I compare two values, with different length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`verifyEval` seems to be using standard Javascript for its expressions, so this should do it;

```
verifyEval | parseInt(storedVars['x']) > parseInt(storedVars['y']) | true
```